# How To Detect Remove or Add from List

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework

Now, I have a database that there are student IDs and Student Names.

```
studentsCollection.Where(c => c.ID.Contains(":"));
```

Then, I just want to take those students that there's "colon" in their ID. And, when I just only use where clause, I will get the error like "edititem is not allowed for this view".
However, when I make the sentence into (below)

```
studentsCollection.Where(c => c.ID.Contains(":")).ToList();
```

add the ToList Function; it will be able to edit but cannot update or even delete.

Does anyone know how I can revise this error ?

***If there is not enough information to know what I'm asking, please tell me, thanks.***

-----**EDIT**-----

Below is my seletedchanged function.

*ERROR situation*: When I only use where clause, I will get "edititem is not allowed for this view"
*CANNOT UPDATE situation*: When I add the ToList Function, I will work; however, I will not update my data.

```
private void StudentsDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedStudents = e.AddedItems[0] as Students;

            var studentsCollection = selectedStudents.Data;

            studentsCollection.AssociationChanged += ColumnsCollection_Changed;
            var studentsViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("StudentsDataViewSource")));

            studentsViewSource.Source = studentsCollection.Where(c => c.ID.Contains(":")).ToList();
        }

        private void ColumnsCollection_Changed(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Remove)
            {
                studySystemEntities.Data.DeleteObject(e.Element as Data);
            }
            else if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Add)
            {
                studySystemEntities.Data.AddObject(e.Element as Data);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add a small but working example showing your problem

Comment: What is the exact error you receive?

Comment: Why downvote?the question may not be precise but nonetheless its a valid programming question

Comment: What kind of application ? ASP.Net, Winform, wpf ... ?

Comment: @Blachshma The application will work if I use ToList, but I won't update the data.

Comment: @DarrenDavies I will get "edititem is not allowed for this view" when I only use where clause. If I add ToList Function, it will work.

Comment: post full code,what you have posted is not enough to detect exact problem

Comment: @CYB when do you get the error? When you compile? When you click a button on your app? What is `studentcollections`? Is it an IQueryable object? The data context?

Comment: @Arran I have updated the post, please take a look, thanks. Then, I will get the error when I click the column of my datagrid, and it's an IEnumerable object I think.